# SQL queries : find what producers have sold ONLY items from a particular date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table T which contains the attributes `N_PRODUCER`, `DATE`, and `ITEM`.
I want to find what producers have sold ONLY items from 1994.

I did this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT N_PRODUCER 
FROM T 
WHERE (DATE=1994);
```

But this is not right, since I need ONLY items sold in 1994. How can I do this?

Comment: ,Which DBMS are you using..?

Comment: I connected SQL to Python

Comment: In fact, I want to get all the N_PRODUCER who sold ITEM in 1994, but only in 1994.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the producers who ONLY sold in 1994 and in no other year, maybe something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT N_PRODUCER
FROM T
WHERE MIN(DATEPART(YEAR, DATE)) = 1994
AND MAX(DATEPART(YEAR, DATE)) = 1994
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of below code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT N_PRODUCER FROM T WHERE  DATEPART(YEAR,[DATE]) =1994
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you want to get only the Year of the Date column.
If this is the case, you can try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT N_PRODUCER FROM T WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, DATE) = 1994
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query in SQL server :

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCER 
FROM Your_table 
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, DATE) = 1994
```

Comment: @Alison,can you provide any sample data and expected output..?

Comment: I tried it again, I have now all those who sold items in 1994, I still have those who also sold items for other DATES

Comment: So, I tried this:
SELECT DISTINCT N_PRODUCER
FROM T
WHERE (N_PRODUCER NOT IN(SELECT N_PRODUCER FROM T WHERE (NB NOT IN(SELECT N_PRODUCER FROM T WHERE (DATEPART(YEAR, DATE) = 1994)))));

Comment: @Alison,Provide sample data and expected result then only we know what you need.

Comment: N_PRODUCER    DATE               ITEM
1                           1994-01-01      2
2                           1978-01_02     8
1                           1994-01-09      4
8                           1994-08-03      1
8                           1999-09-01      6
2                           1997-09-01      7
4                           1993-08-01      3
1                           1994-02-01      5

Comment: @Alison,SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCER FROM Your_table WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, DATE) <> 1994

Comment: I tried it but, I get those which where not sold in 1994